# how can I get the row of value that also occurred in other row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

As a beginner to sql, I have a table like below in PostgreSQL.

```
id  product type  occured_at                  
 1        A    6  2017-03-17 10:21:22.935278
 1        B    6  2017-04-17 10:21:22.941801
 1        B    8  2017-04-17 10:21:22.935278 
 1        B    8  2017-05-17 10:21:22.935278
 1        D    8  2017-06-17 10:21:22.935278
 2        C    4  2017-04-24 10:21:22.938517   
 3        A    8  2017-04-27 10:21:22.941801  
 4        C    8  2017-09-17 10:21:22.941801  
 4        C    6  2017-09-17 10:21:22.941801
 5        D    8  2017-09-17 10:21:22.941801
```

The question is how can I get the id and product which has different types that occurred on the same date. Just like

```
id  product     
 1        B
 4        C
```

If anyone can help me out, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self join is one approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, A.Product
FROM YourTable A
JOIN YourTable B ON A.ID = B.ID
                AND A.Product = B.Product
                AND DATE(A.Occured_at) = DATE(B.Occured_at)
                AND A.Type <> B.Type
```

Comment: I think you need `A.product = B.product` as you can see product A and B both have id = 1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Good call ty

Comment: it's very helpful. thanks both of you for solving the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT product  
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY product
          date_trunc('dat', occured_at)
 HAVING count(DISTINCT type) > 1
```